# Why doesn't this loop stop?

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to take the string "xxxyyyzzz" and split it up into an array that groups the same letters. So I want the output to be ["xxx","yyy","zzz"]. I'm not sure why this code keeps on looping. Any suggestions?

```
def split_up(str)
  i = 1
  result = []
  array = str.split("")
  until array == []
    if array[i] == array[i-1]
      i += 1
    else
      result << array.shift(i).join("")
    end
    i = 1
  end
  result
end

puts split_up("xxxyyyzzz")
```

Comment: I'm not sure that `i = 1` at the end of your loop is what you really want.

Comment: You don't need the `join` either

Comment: You need `i` to actually go up for your program to proceed, but at the end of every single iteration of your loop, you have `i = 1`.

Comment: You could also write `"xxxyyyzzz".each_char.chunk {|e| e}.map {|_,a| a.join} => ["xxx", "yyy", "zzz"]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The looping is because your `until` condition never exits. You are incrementing `i` when the successive characters match, but at the end of the loop you are resetting `i` to `1`.

If you edit this section and add this line:

```
until array == []
  puts i  # new line
```

Then you'll see that `i` is always `1`, and the code keeps printing `1` forever.

Delete the line `i = 1` line and you'll get the result you want.

Also, you may be interested in reading about the Ruby string `scan` method, and pattern matching and capture groups, and using look-ahead and look-behind zero-length assertions, which can match boundaries.

Here is how I would personally accomplish splitting a string at letter boundaries:

```
"xxxyyyzzz".scan(/(.)(\1*)/).map{|a,b| a+b }
=> ["xxx", "yyy", "zzz"]
```

The `scan` method is doing this:

1. `.` matches any character e.g. "x", and the parentheses capture this.
2. `\1*` matches the previous capture any number of time, e.g. "xx", and the parentheses capture this.
3. Thus $1 matches the first character "x" and $2 matches all the repeats "xx".

The scan block concatenates the first character and its repeats, so returns "xxx".

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, this can be solved using scan like this:

```
def split_up(string)
  repeat_alphabets = /(\w)(\1*)/
  string.scan(repeat_alphabets).map do |match|
    match[0] << match[1]
  end
end
```

Explanation:

1. The regular expression matches repeating characters, but due to the construction of the regex [matches occur as pairs of the alphabet and remaining repeated instances](http://rubular.com/r/dBa2JyTU0t).
2. `m[0] << m[1]` joins the matches to form the required string.
3. `map` combines the string into an array and returns the array as it being the last statement.